# Cómo crear una función que devuelva un escalar devuelto a su vez por una consulta SELECT

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta función que devuelve un varchar(max) producto de una consulta recursiva CTE.

```
create function ToBinary(@num int)
 returns varchar(max)
 as
 begin 
  declare @bValue varchar(max);
  with Binario(a) as (
    select @num
    union all
    select a/2 from Binario where a>=2
  )
  select @bValue=reverse(string_agg(a%2,'')) from Binario
  return @bValue
end
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de devolver el resultado del CTE sin utilizar una variable intermedia @bValue. Si en vez de devolver un varchar(max) devuelvo un Table, sin problema, transact no me da error y no necesito la variable @bValue, pero si le indico que la devolución será un varchar(max) me devuelve este error:

> Las instrucciones RETURN de funciones de valores escalares deben incluir un argumento.

El código que me devuelve ese error es este, en el cual devuelvo directamente el resultado del CTE.

```
create function ToBinary(@num int)
returns varchar(max)
as
return 
with Binario(a) as (
  select @num
  union all
  select a/2 from Binario where a>=2
)
select reverse(string_agg(a%2,'')) from Binario
```

Comment: O sea que quieres devolver un table pero colocando varchar como datatype de retorno?

Comment: no, quiero devolver un vachar(max), pero ese varchar(max) es el resultado de un CTE que concatena todos sus resultados en una cadena de texto con la función string_agg. Binario lo que devuelve es una cadena de texto de unos y ceros concatenados, que es el valor el binario del número que le pase en el argumento de la función. No sé si te lo aclaré

Comment: Entendí lo que quieres devolver, pero no por qué en el script que te da error estás devolviendo un table y como retorno colocas varchar(max) como datatype si claramente estás devolviendo una consulta (SELECT).

Comment: Entiendo que cada vez que devuelva una consulta, aunque devuelve un único valor, el valor de devolución de la función ha de ser un Table, ¿verdad? Si quiero devolver un escalar tengo que almacenar el resultado de la consulta en una variable. ¿Sí?

Comment: claro, entiendo que tu consulta va por el lado de por qué razón si devuelvo 1 solo campo de una table, cte, vista, etc. te vez obligado a guardarlo en una variable, bueno, es básicamente porque el dbms no lo interpreta como un valor escalar y con razón, ya que la última consulta deriva de un select, por tanto, un output no escalar.

Comment: Perfecto lsanchezo, intuía algo así, pero por si acaso preferí preguntarlo por si se podía mejorar o había algún detalle que desconocía. Muchas gracias por tu rápida respuesta y gran aclaración.

Comment: Has intentado usar una función tipo tabla? Requiere ser llamado de otra forma pero es más eficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi primer idea fue sugerir una función tipo tabla en vez de una función escalar. Las funciones tipo tabla en línea permiten una ejecución más eficiente porque se integran al código y el optimizador las puede tener en cuenta. Entonces la primer solución quedaba así

```
CREATE FUNCTION ToBinary
(
    @num INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH Binario(a) AS (
    SELECT @num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a / 2
    FROM   Binario
    WHERE  a >= 2
)
SELECT REVERSE(STRING_AGG(a % 2, '')) AS binario
FROM   Binario;
GO
```

Para llamarla, el código es distinto al tradicional ya que se requiere usar APPLY.

```
SELECT b.binario
FROM TablaPrueba o
CROSS APPLY dbo.ToBinary( num) b;
```

Pero luego pensé en hacerlo un poco distinto y deshacerme de la expresión recursiva y solo generar la tabla de números de 0 hasta 30, lo cual permite obtener el equivalente binario hasta de 2,147,483,647 que es el límite de int. Así sí logro tratar el resultado de la consulta como un valor escalar y regresar a la idea de la función escalar.

```
create function ToBinary2(@num int)
returns varchar(35)
as
BEGIN
    return (SELECT STRING_AGG( IIF( @num >= POWER( 2, n), 
                                    CAST( SIGN( @num & POWER( 2, n)) AS CHAR(1))
                                    , '')
                              , '')  WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY n DESC)
            FROM (SELECT TOP (31) ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
                  FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(n),
                       (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) y(n))z(n));
END
GO
```

Eso redujo el tiempo de ejecución en 100,000 líneas de 10 segundos a 4 segundos. Pero quise ver que pasaba si generaba este código como función tipo tabla en línea y quedó así

```
create function ToBinary3(@num int)
returns table
as
return 
    SELECT STRING_AGG( IIF( @num >= POWER( 2, n), 
                                    CAST( SIGN( @num & POWER( 2, n)) AS CHAR(1))
                                    , '')
                              , '')  WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY n DESC) binario
    FROM (SELECT TOP (31) ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 n
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) x(n),
                (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) y(n))z(n);
```

Eso redujo aun más el tiempo de ejecución llegando a 2.3 segundos en vez de los 4 segundos.

Comment: Eres un crack Luis. Muy buen algoritmo para convertir a binario. Gracias por compartirlo. Me ha encantado.